# How to disable "print margin" in Geany

Tags: geany

Is there a way to disable the "print margin" in Geany? I don't know if it is called print margin in general, but at least in ace it is called like that.

Here's a screenshot: [image]

Also I really don't know how it should be useful. To me it's just distracting.

I'm running it on Win 7 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to disable the "print margin" in Geany?

The "print margin" you refer to is called a "Long Line Marker".

To turn off the Long Line Marker:

- Go to "Preferences" > "Editor" > "Display" tab.
- Remove the check mark from Long line marker "Enabled".
- Click "OK".

  [image]

---

#### What is the Long Line Marker?

> The long line marker helps to indicate overly-long lines, or as a hint to the user for when to break the line.
>
> - **Line**
>         Show a thin vertical line in the editor window at the given column position.
> - **Background**
>         Change the background color of characters after the given column position to the color set below. (This is recommended over the
>     Line setting if you use proportional fonts).
> - **Disabled**
>         Don't mark long lines at all.
> - **Long line marker**
>     Set this value to a value greater than zero to specify the column where it should appear.
> - **Long line marker color**
>     Set the color of the long line marker.

Source [Long line marker](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#long-line-marker)

---

#### Further reading

- [Geany User Manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/)